# Touch up down event or swipe up down

Tags: android, widget, imageview, touch-event, swipe-gesture

I am working on some widget. But still couldn't find touch up down event in widget. In my research, widget can use just one click event called setOnClickPendingIntent. But it's like touch down event. I wanna do event like touch up too. In my work if swipe up to down and down to up on imageview, an image will be changed. Please help me or give me some idea...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible from an app widget. App widgets do not get fine-grained touch events.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. But if i see weather widget of android. Swipe up down and click events are working and if we see this link [link](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html) Touch and gesture are available. I have no idea how to do this. I couldn't find any good examples.